# How to prove $|\arctan(2b)-\arctan(2a)| \le 2|b-a|$ for any real numbers $a, b$

Tags: inequality, functional-inequalities

I need to prove the following inequality:

$$|\arctan(2b)-\arctan(2a)| \le 2|b-a|$$

If $a=b$, this is obvious. So,  without loss of generality, I assumed $a < b$.

I defined $f(x) =\arctan(2x)$ and used the mean value theorem in $[a,b]$ and some $a < c < b$:

$$\arctan(2b)-\arctan(2a)|=|f'(c)(b-a)|=\bigg|\frac{2}{1+4c^2}\cdot(b-a)\bigg|=\frac{1}{1+4c^2}\cdot2|b-a|$$

Now, I need to show somehow that $\frac{1}{1+4c^2}\le1$, but I don't know how.
In addition, if there is another way to solve this, I will be happy to know.

Answer (score 2):

$$1+4c^2\geq 1\implies \frac{1}{1+4c^2}\leq 1.$$

Answer (score 0):

You made the most difficult step! Just $1 + 4 c^2 \ge 1$, so $\frac{1}{1 + 4 c^2} \le 1$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the mean value theorem, we have that

$$|\arctan(2b) - \arctan(2a)| = \left|\arctan\left(\frac{2b-2a}{1+4ab}\right) \right| \leq \left| \frac{2b-2a}{1+4ab}\right| \leq 2|b-a|$$

using the tangent angle subtraction formula and $\arctan x \leq x$ for $x \geq 0$

Comment: Why is the last inequality true? And what if $4ab=-1$?

Comment: @Daniel If $4ab=-1$ the inequality is still certainly true, but then the last step wouldn't work. Instead you would get a separate case where $$|\arctan(2b)-\arctan(2a)| = \frac{\pi}{2}$$ but we already knew this since $$a = -\frac{1}{4b} \implies |\arctan(2b) + \arctan(1/2b)| = \frac{\pi}{2}$$ by $|\arctan(x) + \arctan(1/x)| = \frac{\pi}{2}$. But you are right the last inequality only holds if $ab>0$. If $ab < 0$, this can be broken down into cases again.